# Can a Chrome extension monitor XHR events (or other events) from the page it's running against?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Chrome extension that manipulates the content of the page, but the content I'm interested in only shows up when the user has clicked a button and the data has then been loaded from an Ajax call.

At the moment the extension monitors the page with a SetTimeout but it's clumsy.

Can an extension know when an Ajax call has been initiated, and when it ended? or can the extension somehow receive events from the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know an easy way to monitor XHR requests, but you can monitor any changes being made to a page structure by listening to `DOMSubtreeModified` event. So when ajax call is done and elements are added/removed/changed on a page - you will be notified.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", function(event){
        //something has changed
});
```

Comment: It's not really the answer I was hoping for, but it's still a very valuable piece of information, that I didn't know about, so I accept it!

Comment: @Bambax I have a nearly identical scenario, how has the DOMBSubtreeModified worked for you?