# Finding out the requests from the page with a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm looking to identify the network calls made by a page with a chrome extension. These calls may include XHR requests, iframe document loads etc..

I've seen the following SO questions; however they are not helpful in this case.

[Can a Chrome extension monitor XHR events (or other events) from the page it's running against?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277908/can-a-chrome-extension-monitor-xhr-events-or-other-events-from-the-page-its-r)

[Chrome extension: identify web requests of background-page iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22568457/chrome-extension-identify-web-requests-of-background-page-iframe)

I've tried the webRequest api and it doesn't seem to be doing what I was expecting as well. To summarize:

If I'm loading page A; and page A makes an async request to url B, and loads an iframe from url C, I want to be able to retrieve B and C. I already have page A tracked with DomContentLoaded event.

- I can use the DomSubTreeChanged but it's not really what I'm looking for, the calls might not alter the UI.

Comment: _"I've tried the webRequest api and it doesn't seem to be doing what I was expecting as well."_ I'm afraid you'll need to expand on that.

Comment: Have you tried Chrome extension HTTP-Headers?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use the webRequest API to read the response body? If that's correct, then this isn't currently possible - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104058. You'd have to use a content script or chrome.tabs.executeScript to get the page content. Also, can you share the code you currently have and why it's not working as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the listener below to `background.js` solved this problem.

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
        onRequestReceived,
        {urls: ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]},
        ["blocking"]);
```